# ANOVA: Can a very small Residual Sum of Squares be in part due to a dependent variable of small magnitude?

Tags: r, anova, ancova

## Substantive Question:

Could a very small Residual Sums of Squares be due in large part to a variable of small magnitude?

If so, is multiplying the variable by some number (e.g. 10) an appropriate fix? Is there a a more appropriate method to deal with such?

---

## Background

I am analyzing a variable that has a very small magnitude, i.e. the data has a range of 0.000692 to about 0.000781 (For those curious, the value is Mean Diffusivity, a diffusion MRI measure).

When performing an ANCOVA using the car::Anova function in R, the function returns the error

```r
Error in Anova.lm(model) : 
  residual sum of squares is 0 (within rounding error)
```

Which is due to this line in the car package source code:

```r
if (deviance(mod) < sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)) stop("residual sum of squares is 0 (within rounding error)")
```

I assume this has a large part to do with the fact that I am including a large number of covariates in my model, however I also wonder if the small magnitude of the variable in question may also be the culprit. E.g. when I performed the same ANCOVA, but this time multiplying the dependent variable by 10, the car::Anova() function was able to compute it without error.

When I tested the same approach on a variable of larger magnitude, both the original and "multiplied by 10" models had identical F and p values, the only difference being the Sum Sq's changed by a factor of 10<sup>2</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computers can only handle numbers so small. You’re also squaring those small numbers, making them especially small.

You’re fine multiplying all of your data by 10 if that “tricks” the computer into doing the calculation. Think of it as a unit conversion. I don’t know the units for diffusivity, but consider doing quantum physics but measuring lengths in miles. You’d end up with some tiny numbers. When you use more appropriate units like angstroms, your numbers stop being so silly small.

The multiplication by 10 (or whatever) drops out when you divide the mean squared between by mean squared within to get the F-statistic.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! As for the units of diffusivity (which is calculated by fitting tensors to each dMRI voxel), I believe they are either mm^2/s or mm^3/s, but I might be wrong there